# add character to specific field in sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to  add a `+` in a specific field `$4` in a tab delineated file.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr12   9221325 9221448 chr12:9221325-9221448   A2M
chr12   9222330 9222419 chr12:9222330-9222419   A2M
chr12   9223073 9223184 chr12:9223073-9223184   A2M
```

**desired output**

```
chr12   9221325 9221448 +   A2M
chr12   9222330 9222419 +   A2M
chr12   9223073 9223184 +   A2M
```

**sed so far** (no specific to field)

```
sed 's/$/\t+/' < input > output
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$4="+"; print}' yourfile
```

It sets the fourth field to `+` and then print the fields.

Comment: Or if you value brevity, `awk '{$4="+"}1'` should probably do.